# Submit a 'null' to a jsp from an html form

Tags: html, jsp

Forwarding an html form to a jsp page which has an

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

for 'name' parameter to be processed in jsp page. When no name is supplied , I do want the form to be submitted to the jsp and jsp should detect 'null' to process an if-else loop to display a relevant message.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: can you post all the code for your html form? You are submitting the form to a Servlet correct? You should not submit the form to a jsp, because then that will require java code in your jsp which is discouraged. You could do it with javascript too but i doubt you will want that.

Comment: the form has only the input element mentioned. Also I just want the jsp page to detect the a "null" if no value is entered in the input text. I am submitting the form correct as  <form action="display.jsp" method="get">. Yes I can do it with a js script but that's not what I intend to do.

Comment: why not use a servlet? It will make the task a lot easier... You shouldn't be using scriptlets anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I do want the form to be submitted to the jsp and jsp should detect
>   'null' to process an if-else loop to display a relevant message.

You can use this on your  **display.jsp** page to check if value is not null and not empty:

```
<%
String name = request.getParameter("name");
if(name != null && !name.isEmpty()){
%>

<p>name is <%=name%></p>

<%
}else{
%>

<p>name is null or empty!</p>

<% 
}
%>
```

But as mentioned already this is highly discouraged! You should be using a servlet. If you want to see how that can be done, let me know and i'll edit this answer with a better solution.

Comment: thanks ! I used 'name.isEmpty()' to process the input ! it worked !

Comment: nice to hear, no problem!.. != null checks if the parameter is set and isEmpty checks if it is not an empty string.